# Language files wont work with files in other dirs

Tags: php

Im working on a website and wanted to make it multy language.
I found a multy lamguage script on the internet.
I added the files and the php redirect to my site.
It works fine for the pages in my root dir but it doesnt seem to work on the php files located in other dirs in my root.
root/main.php works fine but root/admin/admin.php aint working.
 it gives an error that the server cant find my lang file.
 my lang files are located in root/lang/ and the php script is located in root/include/session.php.

here a copy of the script

```
session_start();

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;

  case 'nl':
  $lang_file = 'lang.nl.php';
  break;


  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';

 }
 include_once 'lang/'.$lang_file;
```

Comment: What does that mean, "doesn't work in upper folders"? What is the problem?

Comment: Should we try to figure what the code is supposed to do? Should we also know the simptoms of "won't work". Also try to be more careful about your writing.

Comment: Well, the relative path to the file you want to include is obviously different from different folders...

Comment: i tried adding the include in the pages it self, but then it wont load my data

Comment: Edited the question hope its more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to include with a relative path, relative to the current script (session.php)

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/lang.en.php';
```

Comment: Replace **include_once 'lang/'.$lang_file;** by **include_once dirname(___FILE___).'/lang/'.$lang_file.'.php';**

If it doesn't work, the error isn't at this location.

Comment: oke i found out how it worked i had to place my lang dir in the include dir and had to remove the .php from your thingy